# reverse nodes of a tree scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Defines the reverse-tree method that receives a tree as a parameter and returns 
invested all its branches:

I do this:

```
(define (reverse-tree t)
  (map (lambda (x)
         (if (list? x)
             (deep-reverse x)
             x))
       (reverse t)))


 (define tree '(40 (28 (9) (32)) (70 (52) (102))))


(reverse-tree tree)
```

I returned this:

```
(((102) (52) 70) ((32) (9) 28) 40)
```

But I need you to return the reversed nodes:

```
(40 (70 (102) (52)) (28 (32) (9)))
```

How do I return to the reversed nods

Comment: I can't help that all of your questions so far all seem to be about binary search trees.  Are you working through an exercise set or assignment or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a BST Imagine that you have procedures for your tree. `(make-tree value left right)`, `tree-value`, `tree-left`, and `treee-right`

```
(define (reverse-tree tree)
  (if (tree-null? tree)
      tree-null
      (make-tree (tree-value tree)
                 (reverse-tree (tree-right tree))
                 (reverse-tree (tree-left tree)))))
```

For a tree that can have more than two children I guess you apply itself on each child and reverse the result.

```
(define (reverse-tree tree)
  (if (tree-null? tree)
      tree-null
      (apply make-tree 
             (tree-value tree)
             (map reverse-tree (reverse (tree-children tree))))))

;; heres the documentation of the tree
(define (make-tree value . children)
  (cons value children))

(define tree-children cdr)
(define tree-value car)
(define tree-null? null?)
(define tree-null '())
```

Comment: returns me an error the second function :
make-tree: expects 2 arguments, but found only 1

Comment: @user3672728 Strange. It's almost as you didn't use my definition with `.` between `value` and `children`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a node either has 0 or 2 branches, here's a simple solution:

```
(define (reverse-tree tree)
  (if (null? tree)
      null
      (let ((root (car tree)) (tree (cdr tree)))
        (if (null? tree)
            (list root)
            (list root (reverse-tree (cadr tree)) (reverse-tree (car tree)))))))
```

testing

```
> (reverse-tree '(40 (28 (9) (32)) (70 (52) (102))))
'(40 (70 (102) (52)) (28 (32) (9)))
```